# How to go to next action onclick of google pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, google-visualization

I have this google pie chart in my mvc application wherein i need to move on to next action on another controller on click of google pie chart section.Here is my pie chhart and eventhandler function

---

```
    <script>
        function drawCharts() {

                // Create the data table.
                var dataP = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                  ['Risk Level', 'Number Of Patients'],
                  ['Low', @Model.RiskLevel[0]],
                  ['High', @Model.RiskLevel[1]],
                  ['Medium', @Model.RiskLevel[2]]
                ]);
var optionsP = {
                is3D: true,
                colors: ['#109618', '#DC3912', '#FF9900'],
                title: 'Risk Level'
            };
var chartP = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
            google.visualization.events.addListener(chartP, 'select', selectHandler);
            chartP.draw(dataP, optionsP);
function selectHandler() {
                var selectedItem = chartP.getSelection()[0];
                if (selectedItem) {
                    var topping = dataP.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
                    if (topping == "High") {
                        //go to action?
                    }
                }
            }
</script>
```

---

can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

```
var selectedItem = chartP.getSelection()[0];
                if (selectedItem) {
                    var topping = dataP.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
                    if (topping == "High") {
                        //go to action?
                        window.open("url to action", "_self", true)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Don't use `var selectedItem = chartP.getSelection()[0];`, as the chart can have zero selected elements, which would cause this to throw an error.  Use this instead: `var selection = chartP.getSelection();` and `if (selection.length > 0) {...}`.  You can then assign `selectedItem` inside the `if` statement.